# oAuth for Google+

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-plus

i tried several things to get Profile Information for google+.

I want to get Access to my GooglePlus Account via oAuth in Order to get Information as it is mentioned here: https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people

I downloaded the google api java client and tried this sample in order to get Access:
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2Draft10 but this sample is deprecated now.
Before i created a client id and client secret!

But every attempt to get an Authorization failed. By the way is searched for tutorials and examples but i did not found anything.
I hope someone out here can help me a little bit.

Comment: Do you need this for Android, a desktop, or a web application?

Comment: I need this for a desktop application!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this non-deprecated documentation and example:
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2